# How to prepare an easy and fast snack rich in protein?

Tags: snacks

I'm going to the gym, usually, everyday. I'm looking for a simple and easy snack, something that I can carry with me to work, to the office, and would help me to recover from my workout. :)

I know some recipes rich in carbohydrates but none rich in proteins :(
(Besides whey protein, of course)

Any tips or recommendation ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has attracted a couple of close votes, probably because of your use of the word "health". We don't address health issues here. I am going to edit your question to eliminate that issue (as well as I can). Please don't be offended. It's fine to ask for high-protein, low carbohydrate recommendations as such. What we will not allow is you asking for "healthy" alternatives. We are cooks, not doctors.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the tip @Jolenealaska :)

Comment: You are ever so welcome. I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @Jolenealaska, for the record, I voted "too broad".

Comment: @Stephie Well done. That may still be an issue.

Comment: As it stands, this question is likely to be closed without moderator input. If it is, please don't be discouraged from contributing here. I am sure you could be a great contributor to the site.

Comment: I definitely agree with the other voters here: this question solicits a wide array of possible answers, as evidenced by the list in the accepted answer plus the couple other answers. If you want to brainstorm, [chat] might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real quick search brings up a list of high-protein snacks that are easy to make up.

[Source](http://dailyburn.com/life/recipes/quick-easy-high-protein-snacks/)

> 1. Crispy Lentil Energy Bites (8.6 g protein per two bites)
> 2. The Best Homemade Granola (8 g protein per half-cup)
> 3. No-Bake Quinoa Peanut Butter Crunch Cups (8 g protein per two cups)
> 4. Chocolate Peanut Butter Protein Bars (5.8 g protein per bar)
> 5. Dark Chocolate Crunchy Coconut Cashew Sesame Bars (9.5 g protein per bar)
> 6. Chocolate Chip Cookie Dough Protein Balls (5 g protein per ball)
> 7. Protein Muffins with Quinoa, Prunes, Dates and Coconut (18.2 g protein per muffin)
> 8. Zesty Black Bean Hummus (16 g protein per ½-cup serving)
> 9. Roasted Chickpeas (21 g protein per ¼-cup serving)
> 10. Portobello Eggs with Sun-Dried Tomatoes and Goat Cheese (16.8 g protein per cap)
> 11. PBJ Yogurt Bowl (22 g protein per serving)
> 12. Paleo Cinnamon Raisin Flatbread (12.2 g protein per flatbread)
> 13. Roasted Edamame, Three Ways (15 g protein per cup)
> 14. Savory Greek Yogurt Three Ways (17 g protein per cup)
> 15. Protein “Brookies” (7 g protein per cookie)

Follow the link above for photos/recipes

Also, some simpler options [HERE](http://www.everydayhealth.com/diet-and-nutrition-pictures/high-protein-power-snacks.aspx)

Just searching for "high protein snacks" prompts a huge amount of resources to play with.

Answer (score 2):

A hard boiled egg is high in protein and comes in a handy natural container.

Answer (score 1):

How about low-fat cottage cheese? It would be easy to put in your bag; it is fairly high in protein, and low in carbohydrates. You can throw it into a smoothy too.

Comment: That's a great idea @Jole! And here in Germany is also very cheap too! :)